# How to find wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am new to wxWidgets. I have checked a couple of tutorials and can write simple code to generate simple GUI in C++.

Sometimes I have problems when I try to find a specific widget, or just a kind of widget. Documentation has some images. For example, if I want a scroll bar, I can search for it and [see a picture](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_scroll_bar.html) too. But often, I have a picture in mind of what I would like to find, but simply don't know how it is called, or what category I should search in. Or probably even more commonly, a widget that would solve some problem already exists, but I just don't know about it.

If there is some online source, where widgets are listed and structured in a logical way along with their images, to quickly find and identify them... I haven't found it.

How can I find widgets to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately wxWidgets doesn't have anything like this currently. What I recommend is running the widgets sample and looking at the controls shown in it. It doesn't show all of them (there are separate samples for most of the more complex or more esoteric widgets), but it does show quite a few.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will certainly find good use with the supplied samples. I think doing something like what I asked about wouldn't be a terribly big task, and it would help the developers immensely. Maybe just a suggestion to consider.